# How can I disable the new Windows 10 search toolbar?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

In Windows 10, they recently introduced this horrific toolbar in the middle of the desktop and I wonder how I can from **Powershell** permanently disable it from ever showing up again?

[image]

I got many machines to manage and I want to automate the disabling of this feature.

Comment: oh wow, have not yet seen this, but this is indeed horrible. Might be possible to remove this using a Group Policy though.

Comment: I've closed the question as duplicate given you can make changes to the registry using Powershell. Once done, the bar will be gone on next reboot.

Comment: Thanks! I got it ! :-)

Comment: Straightforward classic and plain themes accomplish your goal with normal settings.